# Checking for string match in bash script command line arguments

Tags: bash, array, string

I'm clearly missing something basic and would love some enlightenment.  I've seen numerous posts about seeing if your bash command line arguments match a string.  However, I can't get things to work as I would expect.

Here's my current `my.script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$*" =~  .*\.("Rmd"|"tex")$ ]]; then
    echo "Here"
else
    echo "there"
fi
```

I want the "Here" to print if any of the command line arguments end in ".Rmd" or ".tex".  However, it only prints "Here" if the *last* argument ends in ".Rmd" or ".tex".

e.g.

```
$ my.script.sh test.Rmd
Here
$ my.script.sh test.Rmd test.txt
there
$ my.script test.txt test.Rmd
Here
```

I've tried "$@" instead of "$*" but to no avail.

How do I get the desired behavior (ideally without using a for loop)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it only prints `Here` if the last argument ends in `.Rmd` or `.tex`.

Because `"$*"` concatenates all arguments into one string (e.g. `test.Rmd test.txt`) and then `$` in your regex can only match the end of *this string*.

If your regex tried to match a space character as an alternative to the end of the string, it would kinda work; but then it wouldn't be able to tell apart a single argument being `test.Rmd test.txt` from a string resulting from separate arguments `test.Rmd` and `test.txt`. `"$*"` gives you a string that carries no firm information about boundaries between arguments.

There may be cases where `"$*"` is useful, but in many cases it's not what you really want. E.g. `"$*"` for testing "any argument" may give you unexpected results even if you want a match not necessarily at the end. Example:

```
[[ "$*" =~ "lo wo" ]]
```

`Hello world` as an argument will match as expected. But (with the default `$IFS`) two consecutive arguments `Hello` and `world` will also match; none of them contains `lo wo` though.

A loop is really a sane way to do what you want to do.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

message="there"
for a do
   if [[ "$a" =~ \.(Rmd|tex)$ ]]; then
      message="Here"
      break
   fi
done
echo "$message"
```

Note I removed the leading `.*` from your pattern. In general the pattern will match if it matches any part of the string; so you need an explicit `^` (or `$`) to anchor to the beginning (or to the end) of the string; but this means you don't need leading (or trailing) `.*` if you don't want to anchor (still you may want `.*` if you plan to use `$BASH_REMATCH` later).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I think the solution I want is to replace `$` with `($|" ")`, but I'll gladly accept your thorough answer.